# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' , reason: '-[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created a new `tabbed application` in `Xcode`. I am receiving the following error every time I try to type any letters or numbers into a text field.

I noticed that this error started when I checked the box for `"is initial view controller"`

When i have the `ViewController` itself set as the `initial` `ViewController` it will not throw the error. However, when I make a `NavigationController` the `initial` `ViewController` it will throw this error.

Error received:

```
Reminder[46707:4165261] -[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d087af0
2016-03-23 00:48:19.830 Cable tech Reminder[46707:4165261] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d087af0'
```

Comment: please try to put out code

Comment: please post some code

Answer (score 6):

For me this issue was caused because I inadvertently clicked on the Key Commands controls in the attribute inspector. I did not create any commands, but having and empty entry caused any input into a textField to crash.

**Solution :-**
1) Right click on storyboard and ***open as source code***.
2) Search for `keyCommands` and delete that empty keyCommands tag.
3) Clean and Run.

This solved my problem, I hope it will be helpful for you as well.
Cheers